# How to pass an object into an array of object with less variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

How can I push an object for example with {x, y, z} values into an array of another object with only {x, y} values?

```
Vector2 V2List = []

Vector3 V3 = new Vector3(1,2,3);

//.. code here

V2List = [{1, 2}]
```

This is just an example, on my real work, my object has more than 10 of props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Vector3 to a Vector2 list if you initialize with size.

```
var V2List = new Vector2[2];
Vector3 V3 = new Vector3(1,2,3);
V2List[0] = V3;
V2List[1] = {1,2};
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly:

```js
let v2template = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2
};

let v3 = {
  one: 6,
  two: 7,
  three: 8
};

let v2array = [{
    one: 1,
    two: 2
  },
  {
    one: 3,
    two: 4
  },
  {
    one: 5,
    two: 6
  }
];

v2array.push(Object.keys(v2template).reduce(function(prev, item) {
  prev[item] = v3[item];
  return prev;
}, {}));

console.log(v2array);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const V3 = function (x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

const v3 = new V3(1,2,3);

function insert(v3) {
    const arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v3));
    const V2 = [];
    Object.entries(arr).map((item) => {
        (item[0] === 'x' || item[0] === 'y') && V2.push({ [item[0]]: item[1] })
    })
    return V2;
}

console.log(insert(v3));
```